# CKAN systemadmin user and password

Tags: postgresql, admin, ckan

I installed for the first time on my OS X CKAN (And is possible ive made some mistake). Now i want to play with the UI backend but when I go in "login" section it ask me for User/password
I'm using my postgres user and user's password for access it but it give me error. 
If I list the db I can see my user there but when I login it say "user doesn't exist"
So which one is the CKAN Systemadmin access?
Reading in the docs it just say, you shoudl have create this user during installation process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run this paster command to create a sysadmin user:

```
paster --plugin=ckan sysadmin add <username> --config=/etc/ckan/development.ini
```

For more, see http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/paster.html

Comment: cool thanks. Documentation is down since 2 days at least for me, but following your suggestion i found the right doc file in github, thanks